# Batch change filetype associations on OS X

Tags: macos, batch, file-association, sublime-text-3

I just installed Sublime Text 3 beta and would like to re-associate all the filetypes I have linked to ST 2 with ST 3.

Is there any way to perform this as a batch operation?

For example:

```
$ open_all_with_st3 py txt tsv css scss js ...
```

Or better yet, get a list of all types associated with ST 2 and then assign them to ST 3.

I really don't fancy doing the `Get Info->Open With->Change All …` dance with dozens of filetypes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. I opened `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist` and replaced  all occurrences of `com.sublimetext.2` with `com.sublimetext.3`.

Comment: File seems to have a new name & location in Sierra: `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist`